# Combining Inheritance and dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I would like a decorator for a class that will

- Add `dataclass`-ness
- Inherits a superclass
- `mypy` identifies

So far, below was my solution.

```py
import dataclass as dc

# An example superclass
class Base:
    def hello(self) -> None:
        print("hi")

def my_func(base):
    dataclass = dc.dataclass(base)
    
    class new_class(dataclass, Base):
        pass
    return new_class

@my_func
class HasHelloAndDataclass:
    a: int
```

But `mypy` doesn't recognize the `dataclass` part. `mypy` can't calculate `HasHelloAndDataclass`'s `__init__` and attribute `a`. But, the interpreter didn't complain.

How can I make this possible?

Comment: Why would you wrap everything in the decorator? Why not inherit the superclass normally and apply the dataclass decorator to it?

Comment: @JanWillem Actually, I resorted to that method in the end. But I wanted to wrap everything in decorator for pure convenience purpose.